# How to increase row height in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am using xib for creating custom cell. I want to display a label, depending on label text. How to increase row height as well as label height?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    customCell *cell=(customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        UIImage *userimage=[self getUserImage:[userimageURLS  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.userImageViewIv.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
        cell.userImageViewIv.image=userimage;
        cell.userNameLbl.text=[UserName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.commenttxtlbl.text=[postText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"cell created");
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The variable posttext array is not static. It is dynamic.

I have used the above code.

Comment: What did you write in heightForCell ?

Comment: If its >=iso7 refer this
**– tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

```
CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont: LableFont
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(LABLE_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

use this to calculate the size need for your label and then set new frame for that label.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont: LableFont
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(LABLE_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
return textsize.height+somefixvalue;
}
```

Comment: constrainedToSize is deprecated, You should be using: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *attribValue = stringToBeWrittenInTheCell;

   CGFloat labelWidth = WidthOfTheCellLabel;

   titlelblSize = [attribValue
   sizeWithFont:[UIFont 
   boldSystemFontOfSize: FontSize
   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth,labelHeight)
   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

   [attribValue release];
   attribValue = nil;

   return titlelblSize.height;

}
```

static

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return 71.0;
    }
```

or using storyboard/xiv

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways ....

1.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 80;
}
```

2.

```
[tableview setRowHeight:80];
```

Comment: he is asking for dynamic height.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct height use NSString method -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Use it in 2 places: cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath.

In cellForRowAtIndexPathThen set the label's frame height to the height retrieved from this method being run on the specific text for this indexPath.

In heightForRowAtIndexPath, using the same approach, set the height using the same method run on the specific text for this indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all of you but one thing `sizeWithFont` is now deprecated in IOS 7. for IOS 7 just do the below

```
-(CGRect)sizeOfText:(NSString *)str
{
     return [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, LABEL_MAX_HEIGHT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourLabelFontName" size:16.0f]} context:Nil]; //instead of 16.0f put your Label font size 
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // include the below code with yours
    CGRect stringRect=[self sizeOfText:(NSString *)[postText objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    float labelHeight=stringRect.size.height;
    return labelHeight + 100.0f; // here 100.0f is default change it according to your cell height
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // include the below code with yours
    NSString *commentString=[postText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGRect stringRect=[self sizeOfText:commentString];
    cell.commenttxtlbl.text=commentString;
    CGRect newRect=CGRectMake([cell.commenttxtlbl frame].origin.x, [cell.commenttxtlbl frame].origin.x, stringRect.size.width, stringRect.size.height);
    [cell.commenttxtlbl setFrame:newRect]; 
}
```

Hope it'll helpful to all of you..

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageConversation *message = [marrMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize szMaxCell = CGSizeMake(220, 2999);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];    // whatever font you're using to display
    CGSize szCell = [message.message sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:szMaxCell lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
//    NSLog(@"szCell %@",NSStringFromCGSize(szCell));
    if(szCell.height > 120){
        return szCell.height+100;
    }
    return 150;
}
```

Also use the same in CellforRowAtIndexpath

```
rightCell.lblMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
CGSize szMaxCell = CGSizeMake(220, 2999);
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];    // whatever font you're using to display
CGSize szCell = [message.message sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:szMaxCell lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

CGRect lblFrame = rightCell.lblMessage.frame;
lblFrame.size.height = szCell.height;
rightCell.lblMessage.frame = lblFrame;
```

Replace your label name with lblMessage. and you are done.